# Display file in new window from ajax request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, download

I'd like to:

- Run an ajax request that would make a webservice call to a database
  that stores a file (type 'binary')
- Return the file
- Display the file in a separate window

I'm not looking for fully thought out code answer, just an idea of how/if this is possible.

Note: I'd like to do this without any server code but the webservice call which will be written in c#.

Comment: would `window.open("webServiceURL")` work or do you need to format the data?

Comment: Would that work? I dont know. What would be the return type of the WebService? An object?

Comment: The return type would be a DOMWindow object. `window.open()` is the function that makes popup windows

Comment: I was talking about the return object from the webservice

Comment: When you say "display" do you mean show it, like if it was an image? Will these files always be images? This will be akin to the problem we had before with request/responses and mime types.  The file download/upload thing worked fine, but I guess now you're wanting to have a display window open to show the binaries (pictures). Right?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to format the data client-side then I'd look at some of the following technologies:

Some templating solution - I use [jTemplates](http://jtemplates.tpython.com/) but there are other possibilities.

This can take data in JSON format, and present it using an HTML template that you can either store within your page, or as a separate file.

Also - do you want a separate window, or a popup within the current window?

For the latter, checkout [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/#where). Again there are alternatives, but this is pretty flexible.

If you want a separate window, then I'd use window.open(URL) with this loading a new empty page that makes an ajax call to get the data after loading.

Alternatively, you could load the data in the current page, then issue window.open, and within the second window, grab the data from the parent via the window.opener reference.

Comment: When I run the request for the pdf/png/etc from the webservice what would the return type be from that webservice?